# How to do a specific order by in Entity Framework with a mixture of values and nulls

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am using Entity Framework, and I am returning a cut down collection, using Skip and Take, but based on an order by using a nullable date column. I want to order the list in the following order:

- date less than today
- date of today
- date of null
- date in the future

How can you do this in 1 DB query?

```
using (var context = new CustomersDbContext())
{
    var customers = context.Customers.OrderBy(c => c.NextContactDate).Skip(10).Take(10);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can order first by "priority" defined by your rules, then (only applies for equal priorities) use the current criteria like this:

```
var customers = context.Customers
    .OrderBy(c => c.NextContractDate == null ? 2:
        c.NextContactDate < DateTime.Today ? 0 :
        c.NextContactDate > DateTime.Today ? 3 : 1)
    .ThenBy(c => c.NextContractDate)
    .Skip(10).Take(10);
```

Comment: Very clever, didn't realise you could do it like that. Thanks, I'll give that a go!

Comment: I believe the colon before the '3' should be a question mark?

Comment: @eyeballpaul Apparently :)